# How to Call Chart to insert into newly created Word Doc

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am creating a dashboard in Excel and am trying to add a button that creates a report in Word. I can get the work doc to open and add a heading and any text, but am unable to get charts to be pulled into the doc

I tried creating an object that calls the chart, then calling that new object with InsertAfter but that isn't working

```
Sub NewReportDoc()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add

wdApp.Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    wdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:="Report "
    wdApp.Selection.InsertDateTime
    wdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart1")

wdDoc.Content.InsertAfter (cht)

End Sub
```

Hoping to have the chart inserted into the doc, currently when the doc comes up, there is just the title and date

Comment: Drop the parentheses around the object argument in `wdDoc.Content.InsertAfter (cht)` - note the space before the opening parenthesis, that's the VBE saying "thanks, I'll take that object, let-coerce it into a value, and pass that value" -- and since the `Chart` class doesn't have a default member, that should throw an error. Are you not getting any errors?

Comment: That said a `Chart` probably wants to be inserted as an `OLEObject` into a Word document; [`InsertAfter` looks like it's only for text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertafter)

Comment: Got it, I'll look up how OLEObjects work, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a chart directly from Excel only works using copy/paste - there's no option to "pull it across" via the object models (unfortunately!) When going the copy/paste route, it's important to check out the options in Paste Special. Record the steps in a Word macro to get the optimal syntax.`*`

In Word, the object model can be used to create a new chart (same code as for Excel, basically) - don't know if that would work for you.

`*`If the copy/paste result as an Excel chart object, with link, is satisfactory then there is a way to bring it into the Word document without using the Clipboard, by inserting a `LINK` field. It's then possible to break the link so that the chart will not update from the Excel file (assuming that's what is wanted).

A `LINK` field in a Word document will look like the following (Alt+F9 to toggle between field result and field code). This field code is required for inserting the chart as a field. The parts are: the field name, the OLE type, path to the workbook, "range name" of the chart object (this example is a chart object on a worksheet, but it can also be a Chart Sheet), field switches telling Word how to integrate the OLE object.

```
{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "C:\\Test\\SampleChart_2.xlsx" "Sheet1![SampleChart_2.xlsx]Sheet1 Chart 1" \a \p }
```

Inserting the field and unlinking using the Word object model (based on the code in the question):

```
Dim rng As Object 'Word.Range
Dim fldCode As String
Dim fld As Object 'Word.Field

Set rng = wdDoc.Selection.Range
fldCode = "LINK Excel.Sheet.12 " & Chr(34) & "C:\\Test\\SampleChart_2.xlsx" & Chr(34) & " " _
  & Chr(34) & "Sheet1![SampleChart_2.xlsx]Sheet1 Chart 1" & Chr(34) & " \a \p"
Set fld = rng.Fields.Add(Range:=rng, Text:=fldCode, PreserveFormatting:=False)
fld.Unlink
```

Answer (score 0):

In a tutorial on my blog, I explain how to copy and Excel chart and paste it into Word.

Essentially, the important pieces of the code in Excel VBA are:

```
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdRng As Word.Range

' get cursor location
Set wdRng = wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range

' copy chart
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

' paste chart
wdRng.Paste
```

This pastes the chart as a chart, meaning it is editable in Word, and I believe it remains linked to the data in Excel.

For more details, see the tutorial, [Export an Excel Chart to Word](https://peltiertech.com/export-excel-chart-word/).